# A person or a group that shows care for some people but not others

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Good day,

I'm looking for a word to describe a person or group / association that care for some but not for others, without there being a specific reason for doing so. The person or people aren't treated boorishly but simply aren't given the same rewards.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a common word but consider,  [***favoritist[ic]***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=favoritist%2Cfavoritistic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfavoritist%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfavoritistic%3B%2Cc0).

> [favoritism](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RPNi-pKdeNEC&pg=PA99&dq=%22are+favoritists%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIgobcsqGIyQIVTLQaCh3bHw2N#v=onepage&q=%22are%20favoritists%22&f=false): the favoring of one person or group over others with equal claims; partiality [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/favoritism)

Alternately, ***partial*** might fit the bill.

> *partial*
>
> : showing favoritism [WordNet by Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/partial)
>
> : disposed to favor one over another [The American Heritage Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/partial)

Answer (score 1):

You could say they are being **"selective"**:

> Of or characterized by selection; discriminating.

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=selective))

Answer (score 1):

For the apparently random different treatment of individuals:

> **inequitable**: not equitable; unjust or unfair

{[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inequitable)}

> *equitable*, just - fair to all parties as dictated by reason and conscience; "equitable treatment of all citizens"... [Farlex, same
>   link]

For differing treatment of whole groups:

While being *discriminating* (choosing carefully) is usually seen as a laudable trait, being **discriminatory** isn't.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discriminatory) (reformatted):

> discriminatory (adj)
>
> making or showing an unfair or prejudicial distinction between
>   different categories of people or things, especially on the grounds of
>   race, age, or sex: *discriminatory employment practices*

Answer (score 0):

Bias, Favoritism, Cronyism, and Nepotism

Discriminatory could also work, but there is usually  some type of reason for it, whether the person doing it knows it or not. Selective works too, but there are usually reasons why a person is selective as well.

Depending on the circumstances that person could be many different things.

They might not even know why they feel are treating someone different; they might not even know they are doing it.

I have dealt with a lot of this in my life and it sux.

I did find this article if it helps: https://www.scu.edu/ethics/focus-areas/government-ethics/resources/what-is-government-ethics/favoritism-cronyism-and-nepotism/